# Cannot access ASUS ZenWiFi AX (XT8) router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, asus

I picked up a used ASUS ZenWiFi AX (XT8) router that does not create a WiFi network, cannot be found as an AiMesh node, and if I plug in an ethernet cable it says "Unidentified network" in Windows.

A factory reset did not help. When trying rescue mode, the router enters it successfully (as indicated by a magenta LED), but the recovery tool cannot access the router to push firmware to it.

Hardware-wise the router seems to be functional, I get normal LED responses for initialization sequence, rescue mode, and for WPS button press. After being powered on for a while the router gets warm. And if I plug in my Android phone via USB, I get the option to enable USB tethering. But there is no way to access the router.

My theory is that it was bricked by someone flashing the wrong firmware to it, or perhaps the firmware didn't flash correctly or the router didn't reset correctly. Is there any way I can salvage it? Could I access it via the USB port somehow?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try a [Hard Factory Reset](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1046973/)?

Comment: Yes, first thing I tried. Didn't fix it unfortunately.

Comment: It is likely bricked. If you cannot get to it, you cannot even install legitimate firmware.

Comment: Right, it's definitely bricked, I was asking about how to debrick it.